# Excel VBA: Take sum of two columns (all the way down) and insert on new column?

Tags: vba, excel

Example I want the VBA code to take the cells "A1" and "B1" and sum these two in "C1",

Thus it needs to do it with A2, A3, A4... all the way down to the very end of the column and summarize it to the C column.

Can anyone help program something like it?

Comment: Yes, we can help... Please show us what you've tried and how the results have been incorrect. Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for question guidelines.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure you can find the answer easily by searching a bit but here is a piece of code that might be helpful for you:

```
Sub SumColumns()

Dim Nb_Rows As Integer

'Nb_Rows can be any integer
For i = 1 To Nb_Rows
    Range("C" & i).Value = Range("A" & i).Value + Range("B" & i).Value
Next i

End Sub
```

It calculates the value of Ai + Bi and puts it in Ci.
You can choose the value of `Nb_Rows` : if you know exactly the number of rows you want to calculate you can assign the exact value, else just choose a high number so that you're sure it goes through your entire sheet.

Comment: If you don't know the number of rows then you can use something like this... `Nb_Rows = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1", ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count`

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different version using formula - Cells is easier to use with numbers than Range **CELLS(RowNum, ColNum)**

```
Sub SumColumns()

    Dim Nb_Rows As Integer
    Nb_Rows = 4

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Cells(1, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=Sum(RC1, RC2)"
        .Cells(1, 3).AutoFill Destination:=.Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(Nb_Rows, 3))
        .Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(Nb_Rows, 3)) = .Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(Nb_Rows, 3)).Value
        .Cells(Nb_Rows + 1, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R1C:R[-1]C)"
    End With

End Sub
```